# Movie about child infected with alien disease making him have tentacles?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember seeing a movie in a store that I passed up on but am interested in finding again

Title had something to do with "Infection" or "Virus".

Cover had a guy with like a crab arm?

The plot had something to do with a guy trying to find some way to save his child who was mutated by some alien disease, and I think was in government care...

Oh and the kid has tentacles.

(Post edit I never watched it but it was in stores post 2007 and seemed to be featuring a Primarily Caucasian cast)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see this?  Was it a live-action movie?  In English?

Comment: I saw it in stores around 2007 and I believe it was live action. I cannot say if the movie was made in an English speaking country, but it did seem that it was marketed for an English speaking audience.

Comment: From your edit, does that mean you don't think it is *Meatball Machine*?

Comment: No, I dont think its meat ball machine, though obscure guess

Answer (score 5):

Could be [Meatball Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wX4h09moT6g),
[wiki/Meatball_Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meatball_Machine)

> ...During this encounter, Sachiko is attacked by the alien object
> which penetrates her and turns her into a bio-mechanical monster, a
> NecroBorg. These parasites take over human bodies and use their flesh
> to create weapons which they use to fight each other. Yōji is also
> infected and the plot eventually leads to a showdown fight to the
> death between the two would-be lovers. **A side plot concerns a father
> who is out to kill the NecroBorgs who have also infected his
> daughter...**

Comment: Thats certainly something up my alley, but this particular film seemed to be directed for English speakers, or at the very least, I saw it in a store in America, around 2007ish. It also had primarily Caucasian characters on the case (I never ended up buying it to my regret)

Answer (score -1):

Inalienable made 2007 has a boy with tentacles and the virus plot. District 9 has the crab arm man 2009.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please only post one answer at a time; *InAlienable* might be a reasonable answer; you should focus on that and explain in more detail how it matches the question, preferably with some screenshots.